# Which way to merge branches in github?

Tags: github, workflow

Our team has 2 developers. Just as a basic example.. We've been working on our company's website the past few weeks. He's been working on a responsive layout while I've been putting in some work samples. We are nearing the end of the development on the site and we need to merge our 2 branches together. Is there a certain way I should merge them? We attempted to do this yesterday but we had some conflicts and some lines like this were inserted into our code..

```
HEAD>>>>>>>> 

master>>>>>>
```

So I'm not sure if this is working correctly or if we screwed something up along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I always merge the head into the branch and then merge the branch into the head.  It shouldn't matter either way, but you will get conflicts.  The trick is to take each one and make a decision as to what to keep.

Comment: To avoid conflicts, would it be smart to merge often?